# EF Core tools version update 2.1.1

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-2.1

If I run `dotnet ef add testmigration`

I get this warning: `The EF Core tools version '2.1.0-rtm-30799' is older than that of the runtime '2.1.1-rtm-30846'. Update the tools for the latest features and bug fixes.`

So I checked my csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.1.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Which looks correct to me, version 2.1.1.
So I checked the docs, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/install/)

And they suggest the tools entry in the csproj needs to have this package:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.1.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Now a `dotnet restore` complains that:

`warning : The tool 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet' is now included in the .NET Core SDK. Information on resolving this warning is available at (https://aka.ms/dotnetclitools-in-box).`

And `dotnet ef --version` still lists the old one.

So the next thing I do is remove the entry in the `csproj` altogether, now `dotnet ef` still works, but still gives me the old version.

So I figured I somehow must update the dotnet global tools for EF. But a 'dotnet tools list -g' gives me no results.

All very confusing.

Where does the old version come from, how do I get rid of it/update it?

Comment: Install the [latest version of the .NET Core SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/all).

Comment: I have that, or at least the second latest (2.1.301). But your comment triggered me to check for a global.json which turned out to be the problem. tnx.

Comment: @Flores Thanks for helping me to solve the issue

Comment: Hey guys sorry to bring this one back but I have the same problem and I don't have a global.json file anywhere in my solution. Where is this file located?

Comment: If it is not in your path you have a different problem. To make sure issue a dotnet --version in your project folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok.

Turns out that this is caused by having the second latest sdk installed (2.1.301), but somewhere in the path a global.json pinned to version 2.1.300.

Comment: How did you get rid of that warning ? I have sdk v 2.1.302

Comment: If you do a `dotnet --version` in the path of your app, does it say also 2.1.302?

Comment: No, when I run that I get 2.1.403, but yet I still am shown the warning about the EF Core Tools being out of date.

Comment: I get these issues and have 2.1.400 currently

Comment: ..."but somewhere in the path"... Somewhere in what path?  Path of the solution? Project? Visual Studio install???  Could you be more specific in what you mean?

Comment: Never mind.  I resolved the issue by installing the latest `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`

Comment: Google for global.json and you would have found the answer: Either the solution or project path.

Answer (score 2):

```
install-package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Version 2.1.8
```

did it for me

Comment: it worked for me, just remember to run it as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

This error is also shown when you select **a different project** on *Package Manager Console* rather than the `Entity Framework` project in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact problem. I tried deleting bin folders and rebuilding as others have suggested but that never worked. Finally I updated the SDK to 2.1.403 and the issue was resolved.